# 1 reputation point per comment upvote

Tags: feature-request, comments, reputation

The way I see it, comments are used in one of three ways.

1. To gain more information, point the question owner in the correct direction or generally point out why the question is not good.
2. To add information to or correct an answer.
3. Other unimportant waffle.

Both 1 and 2 take knowledge of the subject, and a small amount of time, and generally add to the quality of the overall question or answers. Often it is more suitable to do 1 than actually answer. 3 of course doesn't really matter as it doesn't attract upvotes anyway.

If the comment is correct and useful, it will attract upvotes. It's still hard to get more than a few upvotes on a comment unless the point is really quite obscure and definitely valid. Getting SOMETHING for making an agreed good point (other than the badges of course) seems reasonable, especially as downvoting costs 1 point.

*** Why don't we get 1 reputation point per comment upvote?**

---

> It doesn't of course matter in the slightest, but I'm a sucker for RPG style ever-larger-numbers, and it's frustrating to spend a lot of time browsing about adding comments as best you can without gaining any free numbers..

---

Well, in retrospect, I completely agree with both @Oded and @Louis. I still think that in some ways the reputation system encourages you to do certain things over others, contrary to whats considered to be good SO practice; to a quite massive degree in some regards. However, for the reasons given below, this was indeed a terrible idea - effectively turning comments into mini answers is in no way helpful.

I'll try and think of a better suggestion!

Comment: so we'd need to implement downvoting on comments as well? and a way for people to explain why they up/down voted on a comment?.... hmmm, comments might start to look like answers if we do that ;). And it's never "more suitable to comment than answer".

Comment: No, I figured it would be fine as it was - my thinking was basically just that upvotes on comments are only ever really attracted on good comments, so 'why not'. @Oded makes a very good point though.

Comment: I've seen upvotes on comments that were not good - funny comments, whimsical comments can get a lot of upvotes but contribute nothing of value.

Comment: I think when you make a Feature Request on meta, you should answer the "why?" question, instead of saying "why not?" (and thank you for not reacting negatively at my comment, re-reading it... I sound kinda douche-y. I just haven't taken a coffee yet)

Comment: Upvotes on funny comments is true too, yeah, I tend to notice them more on meta itself, but I've definately seen that sort of thing on SO itself too. Good point with the 'why not why not' - as I say, I guess I was just thinking that some days on SO can feel a bit fruitless. (I know pre-coffee all too well - I require at least 3 before I become human again!)

Comment: Hey SO!  Leave my lols alone!

Comment: People upvote the comments saying "what have you tried" a lot, so this basically gives free reputation to whoever says that

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Why don't we get 1 reputation point per comment upvote?

Because we don't want to encourage commenting. We already have too many comments as it is.

Comments are supposed to be there only in order to clarify things in the post they are on. They are supposed to be transient, things that can be deleted at any time.

Comments of type 1 and 2 **should be incorporated into the post**, then deleted.

Comments of type 3 should be deleted outright.

Comment: Yup, seems fair! I guess it just sometimes feels like you can get a lot of points by adding passable answers as fast as possible, or *no* points by actually trying to do things the 'right' way, and that seems like it should possibly be addressed - based on your answer, I agree this isn't the right way to go about that though!

Comment: I've never actually had to ask a question on SO as the first or second click from a search engine's results gives me what I want. That is not to say that the accepted SO answer is always the one I'm looking for and I use the comments to each posted 'answer' (and the original question) to gauge relevance to my particular problem. They also provide feedback and annotation that I can use to adjust what has been provided for my own purposes. The only type 1 & 2 comments I delete are when the *Answerer* has incorporated my suggestion(s) to their post. Hopefully, I do not submit many type 3's.

Comment: From a *Reviewer* point of view, I reject many edits that attempt to provide updated source code as being in the *Attempts to reply* category. The description for this states *... It should have been written as a comment or an answer.* If the original *Answerer* does not incorporate new comments into their older post, where is this important information supposed to go? Should another answer be posted that largely plagiarizes the original with updated information be submitted? Am I rejecting edits that should stand?

Comment: Repetition + addition != plagiarism, @Jeeped - there's always room for saying, "Jeeped's answer is mostly right, but *additional info*". That said, if someone submits an edit that adds additional information *while preserving the intent of the existing answer*, don't hesitate to approve it if you're able to confirm it is accurate.

Comment: @Shog9 - *plagiarizes* was the wrong term to use and implies malfeasance on the poster's part. I should have used *copies* in its place. Point taken.

Answer (score 14):

I agree with what Oded [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286065/1906307).

One thing I'd like to add. The fact that no reputation is attached to comments makes it so that they can be moderated pretty freely.

Some people *are* already offended that their comments get deleted. Now attach *reputation* to comments, and see the complaint-fest this is going to cause when comments are deleted.

Answer (score -3):

I think this would be a great idea.

It just so happens that questions and answers can be both upvoted *and* downvoted.  If comments were to provide rep, wouldn't we also want to add a way for them to be downvoted without being "flagged"?  Maybe a comment downvote gives -0.5 rep.

Answer (score -5):

To appease anyone genuinely interested in how their comments are received (while not contributing rep points), I would suggest removing the *Comments* sub-category from the *Activities* top-level category on a user's profile page and making it a top-level category. Its current sub-category status dictates that the fields of information do not include the + score as the layout must accommodate other information pulls within the *Activity* category.

As a top-level category, interested users could get a quick update on what comments of theirs are being viewed as productive (e.g. +'s). Standard sorting criteria could be applied although statistics like *Activity* might have to depend on the parent question. I see no problem with *Votes* or *Newest* as those figures already seem to be recorded.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Wrong on both counts. Simply a desire to solicit negative votes through personal opinion.